# What's the difference between global or local variables regarding the main function?

Tags: c, global, local, program-entry-point

While I know what's the difference between local and global variables I just can't understand if it's important at all, especially when talking about local variables inside the main function.
For example what's the difference here except that we can't use the testvar in the second case in other functions?

First Case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int testvar;
```

Second Case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int testvar;
}
```

**Edit: What I mean is that if I am going only to use a variable inside main then does declaring it as global have any advantage Or that in this specefic case nothing different at all?**

Comment: Not really an appropriate question for SO. Do some research. Search for ["c variable scope and lifetime"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+variable+scope+and+lifetime).

Comment: I totally understand that and made a research but I am talking regarding one specific case (In the main function) take a look at my edited post @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: The question is appropriate.

Comment: In this case, nothing really changes. But it is (almost) always better to declare variables in the smallest scope possible to avoid naming collisions and the like. Unless you have a very specific reason to not pass it to any functions that might need it, just declare it locally.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Possibly. I didn't DV or close-vote. I just feel the OP would get a more in-depth explanation elsewhere.

Comment: If you are going to do not fave any other functions, have all code in the `main` using a lots of gotos etc etc, the code will be so bad that the scope of the variables will the least important issue

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I think that's debatable; for me it's not clear what is meant by "any advantage", @Defender; can you, besides the remarks on the positioning in memory and possible naming collisions say what you are aiming for?

Answer (score 3):

Good practice in software engineerIng is to limit the scope of names to where they are used. If `testvar` is declared outside of `main`, then it is visible to code outside `main`. This exposes it to bugs in which some other code uses `testvar` when it was intended to use some other object (either another object with a different name that was mistyped or an object with the same name, but a different instance of it was desired). Additionally, because it is declared with `int testvar;` and not `static int testvar;`, it will be linked with other objects named `testvar` in other modules. This is a serious problem—it happens that one author of some routines used some name like `AmountOfMemory` for their own purposes and another author of other routines used the same name for their own purposes, and both pieces of code work separately, but, when linked into the same program, they break. For this reason, good code avoids global variables.

If `testvar` is declared inside `main`, none of those errors can occur. The probability of writing a good program is increased. Thus, if `testvar` is not needed (by name) outside of `main`, declaring it inside `main` is preferable.

There is also an issue of lifetime. Similarly to scope (where a name is visible), we prefer to limit lifetime (when an object exists). In the case of an object defined inside `main`, its lifetime is effectively the same as an object declared outside of any function—it will exist for the duration of program execution. So lifetime is not a great concern here. However, there is a situation in which it is. In `C`, it is permissible to call `main` inside the function. This is rarely used. However, if it is used and if `testvar` is defined outside `main`, there will be only one instance of it, and all executions of `main` will share them. If `testvar` is defined inside `main`, each execution of `main` will have its own instance of `testvar`, separate from the others.

Another difference between objects defined inside functions and those defined outside functions is that C automatically initializes objects defined outside functions to zero by default. This however would not affect the choice of where to define the object as an explicit initialization can be provided as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**"While I know what's the difference between local and global variables I just can't understand if it's important at all"**

For me, when learning C, I felt like I didn't *really* understand the difference between local and global variables, *until* I understood why it's important.

Eric Postpischil's answer about scope and lifetime says it all.  It's not a mere difference in how and where you can use the variables; it's the broader implications about what can happen because of that access.

So don't think in terms of **"if I am going only to use a variable inside main()"**; think in terms of encapsulation, modularity, interfaces, and shared code.  I would go so far as to suggest *never* using global variables; any time you are tempted to do so, it will be worth the effort to find another way to accomplish what you are trying to do.  Your future self will thank you for solid programming habits you foster now.

Answer (score 0):

> For example what's the difference here except that we can't use the testvar in the second case in other functions?

From a C standard point of view that is actually the main difference (see later for another differance). If you define the variable inside `main` it has **automatic storage duration** and is only accessible using its variable name inside `main`. If you define  the variable outside `main` it has **static storage duration** and can be accessed using its variable name from anywhere in the code.

One difference is that variables with static storage duration are default initialized while variables with automatic storage duration are left uninitialized. So in your first example `testvar` will be initialized to zero while it is uninitialized in the second example.

Comment: Objects with automatic storage duration can be accessed anywhere in the program, by passing their addresses. The **name** of an object is limited to its scope, not its accessibility.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You can pass the address to other functions but you can't directly access the variable in other functions. That's the difference

Comment: Per C 2018 3.1 1, “access” means “to read or modify the value of an object”. When any code reads or modifies the value of an object, even if it does it by means of a pointer, it accesses the object. One can understand the C standard better, more accurately, and more precisely by understanding that a “variable” is actually an identifier (its name) and an object (a region of storage that can hold a value). The identifier and the object are different things with different characteristics. The object is accessible anywhere (but not anytime). The identifier is limited to its scope.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Guess you must be in the nitpick mode. Anyway... answer edited

Comment: Do you expect a computer to read your code intuitively and “know” what you mean even if you make a little mistake here and there? Software engineering means designing for a **machine** that can do nothing but mechanically pick nits. The only way to be a good software engineer is to be thoroughly detail oriented.